# How to create a Notification system in D7?

Tags: 7

I am new to Drupal and was wondering if there is a module that can serve as a Notification system for logged-in users on my site?

Since my nodes consist mainly of images generated by users, I would like for logged in users to be able to see how many members liked their images, made a comment, followed them, etc.

P.S. I read almost all similar posts here and none of them provided any clear explanation. Pointing to active sites that already use "these module(s)" would be of great help.

Thanks in advance,
Milos

Comment: Start off with the Flag module. This will allow users to individually mark content. Next, add the Views module, and if there's a views-related flag sub module, enable that. Views will allow you to query the flag data. Create a block via Views, and assign this to a template region via the Block admin UI. The core statistics module can also be enabled to track page impressions, and this data can also be queried via Views. This forum is better suited to specific questions, your questions are pretty generic and answers can be easily found online.

Comment: @ murraybiscuit - Could you please point me to online answers, I had no luck in the last two days, hence posting here. Will also check your solution proposal. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In the Drupal community, "notifications" are usually referring to *email* notifications sent to users.

Messages sent to users to indicate "likes", etc. are usually called "messages". So you should probably search for "messages" and "messaging" (instead of "notifications") to locate stuff about *this* type of user interaction.

One of the most popular Drupal modules for messages is [**HeartBeat**](https://www.drupal.org/project/Heartbeat):

> Heartbeat displays user activity on a website. This module is an API to log activity. The logged data contains message structures, attributes and variables. Once the activity messages exist in the database, they will be parsed and build into activity streams.

However, the maintainer of **Heatbeat** has recently announced:

> This project will be deprecated. The future would be in the module [**Message**](http://drupal.org/project/message). It's much smaller and it cannot be compared to heartbeat when it comes to features. However the possibilities as API would be the same.

At the time of writing, **Message** is an API that you can use to build the required flagging and messaging by combining it with other modules in the [message stack](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180145). As for social messaging functions, you need to  add those. The **Heartbeat** API already has all the necessary functionality built-in.  Today, it will take much less effort to get something working with **Heartbeat** than with **Message**, but maybe **Message** is still a better option than putting efforts into working with a module about to be depreciated,

Comment: Thanks @Free Radical but according to the author of Heartbeat, this module will be deprecated. I will check the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module to see if it can meet my needs.

Comment: @mikabajic - I wasn't aware of that.  I've updated the answer to describe **Heartbeat** vs. **Message**.